# Django Running on uWSGI with NGiNX - INI Method Not Working

Tags: django, nginx, uwsgi

I'm migrating from `apache` and `mod_wsgi` to `nginx` and `uwsgi`. I'm running Python 3.3 and Django 1.7. I installed `nginx` via `apt-get` and `uwsgi` via `pip` in a virtual environment.

I have my Django project set up and working when I use this command (at `localhost:8000` - see `nginx` configuration below):

`uwsgi --master --processes 4 --socket :8001 --wsgi-file wsgi.py`

But when I put the same configuration in an INI file, it's not working and I'm getting a bad gateway 502 error:

```
502 Bad Gateway
nginx/1.1.19
```

Here is the `uwsgi` configuration:

```
[uwsgi]
base = /path/to/project
wsgi-file = %(base)/proj/wsgi.py
logto = %(base)/proj/logs/uwsgi.log

chdir = %(base)
module = rebo.wsgi.local:application
home = /path/to/virtenvs/proj
master = true
processes = 4
socket = %(base)/proj/proj.sock
# I have tried ``socket = 8001`` as well
chmod-socket = 664
vacuum = true
```

And the command to start:

`uwsgi --ini /path/to/uwsgi.ini`

When I check the log, everything seems to be in order (**note** the `<obfuscated>`  - these are paths and the output shows no errors):

```
*** Starting uWSGI 2.0.10 (64bit) on [Tue Jun 30 12:45:34 2015] ***
compiled with version: 4.6.3 on 23 June 2015 22:56:27
os: Linux-3.2.0-86-generic #124-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jun 17 21:40:14 UTC 2015
nodename: <obfuscated>
machine: x86_64
clock source: unix
detected number of CPU cores: 4
current working directory: <obfuscated>
detected binary path: <obfuscated>
!!! no internal routing support, rebuild with pcre support !!!
chdir() to <obfuscated>
your processes number limit is 59540
your memory page size is 4096 bytes
detected max file descriptor number: 1024
lock engine: pthread robust mutexes
thunder lock: disabled (you can enable it with --thunder-lock)
uwsgi socket 0 bound to UNIX address <obfuscated> fd 3
Python version: 3.3.6 (default, Jan 28 2015, 16:31:42)  [GCC 4.6.3]
Set PythonHome to <obfuscated>
*** Python threads support is disabled. You can enable it with --enable-threads ***
Python main interpreter initialized at 0x24dc440
your server socket listen backlog is limited to 100 connections
your mercy for graceful operations on workers is 60 seconds
mapped 363800 bytes (355 KB) for 4 cores
*** Operational MODE: preforking ***
WSGI app 0 (mountpoint='') ready in 1 seconds on interpreter 0x24dc440 pid: 12091 (default app)
mountpoint  already configured. skip.
*** uWSGI is running in multiple interpreter mode ***
spawned uWSGI master process (pid: 12091)
spawned uWSGI worker 1 (pid: 12095, cores: 1)
spawned uWSGI worker 2 (pid: 12096, cores: 1)
spawned uWSGI worker 3 (pid: 12097, cores: 1)
spawned uWSGI worker 4 (pid: 12098, cores: 1)
```

Finally, here is my `nginx` configuration:

```
upstream proj {
    server unix:///path/to/project/proj/proj.sock;
    # I have tried ``server 127.0.0.1:8001;`` as well
}

server {
    listen 8000;
    server_name 127.0.0.1;
    root /path/to/project;
    access_log /var/www/proj/access.log;
    error_log /var/www/proj/error.log;

    location /static/ {
        alias /path/to/project/proj/static/;
        expires 30d;
    }

    location /media/ {
        alias /path/to/project/proj/media/;
        expires 30d;
    }

    location / {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass proj;
    }
}
```

I have put this together from various sources and it seems to have the right ingredients, but yet it's still not working after quite a bit trial and error.

Comment: look at this: http://www.django-tips.com/tip/deploying-django-project-with-nginx-and-uwsgi/3/

Comment: `module = rebo.wsgi.local` shoud be `module = rebo.wsgi:application` ?

Comment: The module actually lives at `rebo.wsgi.local` so you are saying it should be `rebo.wsgi.local:application`?

Comment: which module? yes, `:application` must be there

Comment: My apologies... I should have mentioned, but I tried this early on. I have tried several things and I didn't list them all. It didn't help.

Comment: @doniyor I appreciate the tip, but I have spent a lot of time reading docs that cover the same material. I think it's clear that there is more than one way to configure this stack, so specific tips are going to be more helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure which document I read that lead me down this faulty path, but I was using only the number for the INI socket configuration:

```
# WRONG!!!
socket = 8001
```

Should be, just llike the manual command line method:

```
# CORRECT
socket = :8001
```

Or like most docs describe:

```
# ALSO CORRECT, and probably better
socket = 127.0.0.1:8001
```

I think this one of those times where I probably did have this piece of configuration correct, but in haste, I changed it along with other variables (a troubleshooting no-no) and carried it with me, wrong...

Thanks for the feedback and comments. Hopefully this will help at least one other person out there ;-)